# BootStrap 4 make different size images same size in row of columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a responsive row of 4 images that are the same size even though there different(640x799, 640x479, .....). I've been trying to do it with columns and img-fluid, but the shorter size don't fill the column height and the others do. Any help or resources to look at would be great.

Below is the kind of layout I have.

html

```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          .....
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Bootsrap's `img-fluid` sets <quote> `max-width: 100%;` & `height: auto;` _ So you either need to override this in your own `styles.css` or create an `img` style that includes `height: 100%`

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing this both as a quick fix. The best way would be to make sure your images are the same height and width as they will all scale the same. If this is not an option then one of these might help;

Option 1: 
- set the height on each image (works to keep them all inline but the images won't be responsive unless you add media queries in your css and alter the set height)

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="class-name">
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-fluid">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      .....
   </div>
</div>

.class-name img {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 100%;
}
```

Option 2: You can add a parent div to the columns and then set the height and width of that div. This would allow you to set the height of the images to 100% and the width to 100%.

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="parent-div>
          <img class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="parent-div>
          <img class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
      .....
   </div>
</div>

.parent-div {
 height: 500px; 
 width: 100%;
}

.parent-div img {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Both options would need media queries in CSS to make sure they scale down when viewing on a tablet or phone.